# How to arrange dynamically sized UILabels vertically?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uilabel

Let's say I have two `UILabels` positioned vertically below each other in a `UITableViewCell`. The line break mode is set to `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` for both.

Their horizontal size is fixed, but both can stretch vertically based on how much text they display. How do I position the one that's below dynamically so that they would never overlap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i use this function to get the height of the text, and then set  the second label height to the result.

```
- (CGFloat)HeightOfText:(NSString *)textToMesure widthOfLabel:(CGFloat)width
{
    UIFont *textFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
    CGSize ts = [textToMesure sizeWithFont:textFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width-20.0, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return ts.height+25.0; //you can change the last number to fit the space you wish to have between the labels.
}
```

and you use it like that:

```
NSString *firstLabelText = @"the text";
CGFloat textSize = [self HeightOfText:firstLabelText widthOfLabel:firstLabel.frame.size.width];
```

then use "textSize" to set the second label height.

hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

Try -[UILabel sizeThatFits:].  Say you're laying the labels out in a 300px wide column, you can pass in a size of (300,99999), and it'll tell you the size it actually needs to fit that text in.  You can use that to adjust the frames of your labels appropriately.

Comment: A better answer @shani's because `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` won't include the margins that a UILabel will add but asking the UILabel to size itself using `sizeToFit` will :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answers. I have been experiencing in the meantime and what I have found is that `sizeToFit` and `sizeWithFont` methods basically give the same results. Moreover, it also helps to set the number of lines value of the `UILabel` to 0 as it has been outlined in other posts.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar by resetting the frame of the view below (assuming you've already done sizeWithFont or sizeThatFits and resized the labels). Similar to this:

```
- (void)positionView:(UIView *)aView belowView:(UIView *)anotherView withPadding:(int)padding
{
   CGRect aFrame = aView.frame;
   if (anotherView)
   {
      aFrame = (anotherView.frame.origin.y + anotherView.frame.size.height);
   }
   aFrame.origin.y += padding;
   aView.frame = aFrame;
}
```